# belongs_to of associated has_many through not being recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, orm

I have three models making up a basic `has_many through` relationship:

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  validates_presence_of :user, :ride, :role, :required_seats
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :ride
end

class Ride < ApplicationRecord
    validates_presence_of :origin, :destination, :leave_at, :arrive_at, :price, :seats
    has_many :bookings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :bookings
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :bookings, :allow_destroy => true
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password
  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password_digest
  has_many :bookings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :rides, through: :bookings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bookings, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

When running a model spec below:

```
RSpec.describe Booking, type: :model do
  it { should belong_to(:users) }
  it { should belong_to(:rides) }
```

it returns

```
Failure/Error: it { should belong_to(:users) }
       Expected Booking to have a belongs_to association called users (no association called users)

Failure/Error: it { should belong_to(:rides) }
       Expected Booking to have a belongs_to association called rides (no association called rides)
```

The `belongs_to` association has clearly been made in the join model `bookings', yet it is not being recognized in the model.

The `bookings` table has a `user_id` and `ride_id` column, with foreign keys assigned to their respective tables.

I've been stuck on this for a week now, any help would be appreciated as to why this could be happening!

Comment: You are using plurals on your spec (:userS and :rideS), try using the singular name, since you have "belongs_to :user" it should "belong to :user".

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as [arieljuod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1430810/arieljuod) rightfully pointed out, the models in my spec should have been singular instead of plural.

```
RSpec.describe Booking, type: :model do
  it { should belong_to(:user) }
  it { should belong_to(:ride) }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you [mark your own answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).